# custom appcelerator table search field

Tags: search, appcelerator

I'm developing an `iOS 4.3` app for a client using `Appcelerator Titanium SDK 1.6.2`.

I need to filter a tables results but, per the design spec, cant have the search bar attached to the table. When I use the SearchBar element and attach it to the tables search attribute its automatically added to the head of the table.

Is there a way to define a custom search field or force the SearchBar element to detach from the table?

Thanks for your help,

**Josey**

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to add the search bar to the table...

can you post some sample code so I can get  better understanding of you implementation?